# Copy Textarea with Zero Clipboard

Tags: javascript, flash, zeroclipboard

Is there a way to copy the textarea to the clipboard without a button?

What I'm trying to do is have a Short URL display on my site so when you click the link (or text), it copies to the clipboard and fades out with new text fading in that says "Copied!". The links/text will automatically be generated with bit.ly with my custom domain.

**Example:**

Short URL: shrt.lnk/abc123 (Regular)
Short URL: Copied! (On Click)

Anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try clip-j instead. [Here](https://github.com/Triforcey/clip-j) it is. This is a pure JavaScript solution that takes advantage of `document.execCommand('copy');` witch is supported by all major browsers, with other commands to work around the limitation of having to be able to see a text input, do you doing see anything! Plus this doesn't have to work through a button, clicking a link will work just fine!

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do it without the button because Flash 10+ requires a click from the actual button. However, if you use the actual button with text in it, or superimpose button on the text as done here: http://jsfiddle.net/C9KjH then it is a possible workaround in your case.

Comment: Where do you see this "param1" in the AS file?

Comment: The function to modify starts on line 71 of the AS file

Comment: Oh sorry I used decompiler to analyze it - go ahead and put whatever the correct variable name is instead of "param1"

Comment: If not having Flash Builder or Flash Pro,  try the Adobe Flex SDK as free alternative to compile AS3. Hope these links help: http://www.flashdevelop.org/                     http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3                     http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html

Comment: Hmm. Doesn't seem to be working. Perhaps I screwed something up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16471/discussion-between-sajawikio-and-christopher-burton)